# exporting war and building maven war

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, deployment

we have java spring rest project. we are observing strange behavior in deploying war.
If we export war from **Spring** tool suite (**STS**) and deploy in **tomcat** server, application is working fine.

If we **build war** using **maven** install and deploy in tomcat server, application is not running, it is complaining

> "nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [] found for dependency"

Can anyone please suggest how to get rid of this

Comment: Then you haven't setup your pom correctly and probably have been messing around with your classpath and local eclipse settings.

Comment: So please add your `pom.xml`.